# AutoFixture.Freeze IEnumerable of Mocks

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, autofixture

I'm very comfortable using `AutoFixture.Freeze<Mock<IViolationChecker>>()` to setup a class for testing with `.Verify()` and `.Setup()`.

However, in the class I'm working on takes an enumerable of `IViolationChecker`

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IViolationChecker> _violationCheckers;
```

How can I use `AutoFixture.Freeze` to define my list of `IViolationChecker`? I've used

```
var violationCheckers = AutoFixture.Freeze<Mock<IEnumerable<IViolationChecker>>>();
```

But I'm not sure how I would write the `.Verify()` or `.Setup()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to freeze the collection and use `Mock.Get` for each item to get the mocks for setup and verification.

```
//Arrange
var violationCheckers = AutoFixture.Freeze<IEnumerable<IViolationChecker>>();
var mocks = violationCheckers.Select(item => Mock.Get(item));
foreach (var mock in mocks) {
    mock.Setup(_ => _.SomethingHere()).Verifiable(); //setup mock as desired.
}

//...

//Act
//...exercise member under test

//Assert
foreach(var mock in mocks) {
    mock.Verify(_ => /* some predicate*/, Times.Once);
    //OR
    //mock.Verify();
}

//...
```